# dynamic URL routing in django displaying 'item' on each url

Tags: django, url, dynamic, routes

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import Product
from .forms import ProductForm, RawProductForm


def dynamic_lookup_view(request,id):
    object=get_object_or_404(Product,id=id)
    context = {
        'object': object
    }
    return render (request,"products/product_detail.html",context)
```

**product_detail.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content  %}
  <p>
    {{object.title}},{{object.price}},{{object.description}}
  </p>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
path('products/<int:id>/',dynamic_lookup_view,name='product'),
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10000, 
    blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hello</title>
</head>
<body> 


{% block content %}

replace me!

{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

> above is my model
>   App name is 'Products' with 3 product object (in admin panel) django 2.1.7
>   please help me I tried everything and  searched a lot about this bt same problem.
>   on changing product id in the browser url it is displaying 'Item' on
>   every product url instead of individual product data.

[this output is coming for each product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HW3K.jpg)

[project dir screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kz5C4.jpg)

Comment: Can you provide the Product model? In the Admin panel, your product have different names?

Comment: What do you mean when you say that it is displaying 'item' on every product URL? Does products/4/ redirect to products/item/?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOmLL.jpg this is displayed instead of product form data

Comment: but the url you're showing us is /products/ not /products/4. None of the code you're showing here is relevant for /products/

Comment: Yes I changed the url path I was experimenting  bt earlier it was this products/1/ or /2 bt same issue

Comment: in products/1 or /2 or /3 it is showing same page with 'Item' on it

Comment: Can you show code for your base.html code and why you doing {% extends '../../base.html' %} instead you can simple write {% extends 'base.html' %}

Comment: I was experimenting earlier it was this only {%extends 'base.html' %} but not working same issue

Answer (score 0):

problem solved it was my mistake actually my template is overridden due to same name template outside my app. sorry but thank u very much for looking.